# How to bind a selected row data from the Mat-table in to popup input fields in angular using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a sample angular app using angular material components.I have taken a simple table in my main page with employee details.

I need to select employee row and based on the selected row I need to bind the data in the popup.

can any body please help me how to access the selected row data in my popup .......?

please access my [sample app here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-demo-by-heena?file=app%2Ftable.component.ts)

Any help would be greatly appreciated....!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to inject the data into your dialog component using MAT_DIALOG_DATA... I can see this imported in your project so you seem to already be aware of this part, but may be a little confused on how to implement it... please see below.

You will also need to import inject

```
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
```

Then in your OpenPopup class constructor setup inject MAT_DIALOG_DATA like below.

**Please note:** Any data you pass into your dialog will need to be accessed using the **data** variable.

```
 export class OpenPopup {

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<OpenPopup> ) {

   }
```

Then in your openPopup() method in your TableComponent class pass the selected array into your dialog

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(OpenPopup, {
      width: '600px', height: '400px',
      data: this.selection['_selected']
    });
```

Once inside of your dialog use it in the HTML like this.

**Please Note:** Because this example is passing the entire selected array to your dialog the example accesses the first select row statically via the [0] index. If you intend to pass multiple values to the dialog you will need to revise your html in the dialog to handle that... if you intend to only pass a single row then revise the data variable in your openPopup() method and only pass one there.

```
<h3>Update Row Data</h3><br/>
{{data | json}}



<!-- -------- INPUT FIELDS ----------  --> 
<div>
    <mat-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">  
        <input matInput placeholder="First Name "  id="" name="" [value]="data[0].empName">
    </mat-input-container>
</div>
<br/><br/>

<div>
    <mat-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">  
        <input matInput placeholder="Last Name "  id="" name="" [value]="data[0].empName">
    </mat-input-container>
</div>
<br/><br/>

<div>
    <mat-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">  
        <input matInput placeholder="Title "  name="" [value]="data[0].title">
    </mat-input-container>
</div>
<br/><br/>

<div>
    <mat-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">  
        <input matInput placeholder="Address "  name="" [value]="data[0].address">
    </mat-input-container>
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

Comment: You changed the TableComponent constructor to public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<OpenPopup>... so this.dialog.open is now undefined... you would need this.dialogRef.open now... this constructor was ok before, why are you changing this one?

Comment: Make sure to follow the steps provided above in my answer exactly as they are to replicate the answer before making other changes. The changes I recommended were to the OpenPopup class constructor and not the TableComponent constructor

Comment: Please see edit to answer above, hopefully that will show where those constructor changes need to be.

Comment: yes yes i got it .... Its working now... Im just taking it for the save functionality...............!